# Issue with CI Bonifre Module

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

Im using the latest version of bonfire. I created new module called 'contacts' which works fine on my localhost (public/index.php/admin/content/contacts).

I uploaded everything to the server and it works perfect... except my module. It gives me a 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. On my localhost the controllers of my new module created by the module builder work fine. But when I tried the same in the production environment I got the 404 error when viewing the module in the admin panel.

To fix the issue you need to capitalise all the controller file in your new module /application/modules/. Make sure that the class names in the controllers are capitalised as well. This fixed the issue for me.

Not sure why the localhost acts differently. Hope that helps.